# Sum values of objects which are inside an array with underscore.js and reduce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to sum values of objects inside and array with underscore.js and its reduce method. But it looks like I'm doing something wrong. Where's my problem?

```
let list = [{ title: 'one', time: 75 },
        { title: 'two', time: 200 },
        { title: 'three', time: 500 }]

let sum = _.reduce(list, (f, s) => {
    console.log(f.time); // this logs 75
    f.time + s.time
})

console.log(sum); // Cannot read property 'time' of undefined
```

Comment: have to return something...read the docs

Comment: actually, I forgot about return. But when I tried to return and display that value on html I got NaN

Comment: You forgot to give it an initial value. `..., 0)` at the end of `reduce`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the native `reduce` since `list` is already an array.

`reduce` callback should return something, and have an initial value.

Try this:

```js
let list = [{ title: 'one', time: 75 },
        { title: 'two', time: 200 },
        { title: 'three', time: 500 }];

let sum = list.reduce((s, f) => {
    return s + f.time;               // return the sum of the accumulator and the current time, as the the new accumulator
}, 0);                               // initial value of 0

console.log(sum);
```

**Note:** That `reduce` call can be shortened even more if we omit the block and use the implicit return of the arrow function:

```
let sum = list.reduce((s, f) => s + f.time, 0);
```